# What does "fraction of Blue Book value" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

On this page :
http://boston.craigslist.org/i/autos
the fourth point of "How to recognize a vehicle scam attempt on CL"

What does "fraction of blue book value" mean?

Comment: @Macro's answer is correct, in both English usage and auto valuation context. If you want to know more about this practice, or anything beyond the fact that percentage implies multiplier less than 1.00, you could ask about this on Personal Finance SE http://money.stackexchange.com too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Kelley Blue Book](http://www.kbb.com/) is a commonly used resource to value new and used cars. Fraction of the blue book value presumably refers to a price that is a fractional multiple of the blue book value.

As it relates to scamming on craiglist, I would imagine that many scam artists try to draw in potential victims by claiming they're selling a car at a fraction of the blue book value.

Comment: "Fraction" of course literally means anything up to and including 1/1 or the whole thing in a mathematical context, but idiomatically implies a significantly smaller part than the whole.

Answer (score 0):

The [Blue Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelley_Blue_Book) value of a car is the *dealer* or "wholesale" value of a car. It's unlikely that a buyer would get a better deal than that.

"A fraction of Blue Book value" means "cheaper than the best possible deal," i.e. one that's "too good to be true."

The only way that someone could "reasonably" offer such a deal is if the goods were stolen or counterfeit.

Answer (score -1):

[KBB value](https://www.definition.net/define/kbb) is given based on the vehicle's condition and similar prices of your car in your location.

Vehicle conditions are divided into four grades. Excellent, Very Good, Good and Fair. You can get your KBB value for your car in the following link https://www.kbb.com/whats-my-car-worth/.

Comment: This does not address the question.